# Determining whether eigenvalues are positive, negative or 0.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider $ u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}$ for $0 <  x < l,$
>
> with the boundary conditions $$u(0, t)
> = 0, u_x(l, t) = 0$$
>
> and the initial conditions $$u(x, 0) = x, u_t (x, 0) = 0.$$
>   Find the solution explicitly in series form.

In solution manual, writer has computed $$\frac {X''} X=-\mu^2 (*)$$
$$ \frac{T'}T=-c^2\beta ^2(**)$$

which means he/she assumed that eigenvalues are negative. Does that mean when eigenvalues are 0 or positive he/she got trivial solutions that's why only considered negative eigenvalues? Also in $(*)$ why $c^2 $ is eliminated whereas it appears in $(**)$?

My other doubt is that one of the initial conditions is not homogeneous so how do we apply the method of separation of variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily check what happens when the eigenvalues are assumed $0$ or positive. For $0$ eigenvalues:

$$X''(x) = 0 \ \text{ and } \ T''(t) = 0 \\ X(x) = Ax + B \ \text{ and } \ T(t) = Ct + D$$
For some constants $A, B, C, D$ determiend by the boundary conditions.

$X(0) = 0 \implies B = 0 \\ X'(l) = 0 \implies A = 0$

So the only solution is trivial.

Now for positive eigenvalues:

$$X''(x) = \frac{\lambda^2}{c^2} X(x) \\ T''(t) = \lambda^2 T(t)$$
Which has solutions:
$$X(x) = A\cosh(\frac{\lambda}{c}x) + B\sinh(\frac{\lambda}{c}x) \\ T(t) = C\cosh(\lambda t) + D\sinh(\lambda t)$$

$x(0) = 0 \implies A = 0 \\ x'(l) = 0 \implies \frac{\lambda}{c}A \sinh(\frac{\lambda}{c}L) = 0$

$\sinh(x)$ only has $1$ zero at $x = 0$, so either $\lambda = 0$, or $A = 0$.

Either way, we get the trivial solution, so that we can only have negative eigenvalues.

Notice that I attached the $c^2$ term with the $X$ function. It is most common to attach it with the $T$ function, as your book did, but this is always choice. It will *not* be attached to both. This happens directly from separation of variables. You get the equation:

$$c^2 \frac{X''}{X} = \frac{T''}{T} = \text{constant} \ \ \ \ \text{ OR } \ \ \ 
 \frac{X''}{X} = \frac{T''}{c^2 T} = \text{constant}$$

Where the constant will end up being your eigenvalues. The only difference is where which equation the $c^2$ constant appears in, but they are equivalent representations

It should also be noted that Sturm-Liouville theory will give you the answer you want immediately, but it is always good practice to run through things anyways.

Comment: Great, I was writing about that $c^2$ , and you have answered it too. I got it totally, thanks!

Comment: One more question:) What I realised is that they are checking all eigenvalues when computing X(x), but when computing T(t) they only consider whatever the eigenvalues worked out in X(x). I mean if I get trivial solutions with positive eigenvalues when computing X(x) does that mean I would get trivial solutions  with positive eigenvalues when computing T(t) too? @infinitylord

Comment: @LeylaAlkan: No. Either way, you will have to apply the boundary conditions for $X(x)$ at some point, which for non-negative eigenvalues will produce the trivial solution $u(x,t) = 0$. However, it is not generally true that the boundary condition for *both* $X$ and $T$ would individually lead you to the trivial solution.

Comment: I am confused a bit now

Comment: @LeylaAlkan: I am saying that if you tried to apply boundary conditions for $T$ first with non-negative eigenvalues, it might not tell you that the solution is trivial. The trivial part comes from the fact that $X(x) = 0$, so that $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

After separation of variables, you get $\frac{X''}{X}=C$, a constant. The eigenvalues $\mu^2$ are defined as $-C$, because usually (in this case, it is) solutions only exist for $\mu^2\geq 0$ (maybe even only $\mu^2> 0$). Working with $C\leq 0$ is less nice, because you constantly need to keep the minus sign in mind, so we work with $-C$.

After separation of variables, $u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}$ turns into $XT''=c^2X''T$, which gives us $\frac{X''}{X}=\frac{T''}{c^2T}=C=-\mu^2$, so $\frac{X''}{X}=-\mu^2$ and $\frac{T''}{T}=-c^2\mu^2$.

The method of separation of variables has nothing to do with the initial conditions, so it even works without any initial conditions.

I hope I answered all of your questions.

Comment: So do we only check whether the PDE itself and the boundary conditions are homogeneous and linear, to apply the method of separation of variables?